# How to prevent qmake from adding a `_d` suffix to the libraries in the Debug mode?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

My Qt project links with the library python27.lib on Windows 8.1. The .pro file contains the following line:

```
win32:LIBS += C:\Python27_11\libs\python27.lib
```

When building the project in Release mode, it links correctly with python27.lib.

When building the project in Debug mode, it looks for python27_d.lib:

```
Error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'python27_d.lib'
```

How to enforce linking with python27.lib in the Debug mode?

Thank you in advance!

Roni.

P.S. I tried to use different syntax `win32:LIBS += -LC:/Python27_11/libs -lpython27`, and to enclose the declaration into `CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {}`. None of these worked.

The system info:
Qt Creator 3.5.1 (opensource)
Based on Qt 5.5.1 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit)
The OS is Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit

Comment: You basically need to get the debug version of the Python library, I believe (could be wrong, I usually use MinGW for Windows stuff, but see the suggested duplicate).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's one of the python headers that opens the "_d.lib" if one of the "DEBUG" or "_DEBUG" macros are set, I don't think this is a qtcreator thing

Comment: Thank you, @hyde, both for the link and for the suggestion. In this particular case I could probably build Python debug library from the source (it is not available pre-built). However I ran into a similar problem before. Sometimes the 3d party libraries are not available in both release and debug version. I would like to to control what library I am linking with, instead of QtCreator making decision for me (even if it is a good practice).

Comment: @roni just do something like `#undef _DEBUG` before including python.h (and re-define it in debug mode afterwards)

Comment: Thank you, @PeterT, you are probably right, in might not be QtCreator itself. I hope to find correct syntax/setting for the *.pro file that will enforce linking with the right library.

Comment: again, nothing to do with the *.pro file QtCreator or qmake, somewhere in the python header there's a `#pragma comment(lib,"python27_d.lib")`

Comment: Thank you very much, @PeterT! The "#undef _DEBUG" solution worked!

Comment: just don't forget to re-enable it in debug mode like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32425901/777689

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I used. Thanks again!