# Visual Studio CL.exe cannot find python.h

Tags: python, c, visual-studio, include-path

I am trying to include this line in my .c code

```
#include <Python.h>
```

All I have in my helloworld.c is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hi, this is me. \n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I haven't wrote anything that use the python.h yet, since I haven't been able to
compile. This is the error I get:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Python.h': No such file or directory
```

I am using CL.exe, the visual studio 2017 's command line compiler to run this:

```
cl /LD helloworld.c
```

How do I let the compiler know where my python.h is?

Comment: `/LD`? Are you sure?

Comment: You want use option `/?` and read?

Comment: yes, I am trying to write a .DLL for my python to call.

Comment: Sorry I should have said that.

Comment: This might help as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx - still you need to read it ;-)

Comment: Ohwell, did you install the python stuff?

Comment: Yes, I am on 3.6.5

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16200997/694576

Comment: Have you seen this: https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/windows.html?

Comment: ah this worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: cl /LD /I C:\python\include hello.c C:\python\libs\python36.lib

Answer (score 2):

```
cl /LD /I C:\python\include hello.c C:\python\libs\python36.lib
```